# Combine text and a double in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I need to display text and a double in a Text widget but I am getting an error. This should be a simple thing to do.

Here is the code:

```
double commission = 0.0;

const Text('Commission: ${commission}'),
```

Here is the error

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.dartconst_constructor_param_type_mismatch
Unnecessary braces in a string interpolation.
Try removing the braces.dartunnecessary_brace_in_string_interps
Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
```

Nothing I try works. I initialized the variable but it still doesn't work.

This should be easy but how do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the keyword `const`. see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Remove `const` because You are trying to embed dynamic value in your widget such that its content can change dynamically where you can't use `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to add 'const' with dynamic value.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double commission = 0.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Commission : ${commission}'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        // The title text which will be shown on the action bar
        title: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```